# Node losing gravity after SCNAction

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

I'd like to drop an object and then move it back to the top and let it fall again. The first part is working, but then the node seems to lose its gravity and isn't falling again. It looks like its physics body stays on the floor and is not moved by the SCNActions. What is the solution for this? Thanks

```
    let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: boxSize, height: 0.001, length: boxSize, chamferRadius: 0), options:nil)
    node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: shape)
    ...
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 5 
    let actions = SCNAction.sequence([
        SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 3, z: -2), duration: 1),
        SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi*2, around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), duration: 1)
    ])
    node.runAction(actions)
    //node.presentation.runAction(actions) //also not working
    SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to let the physics simulation know that the physics body has moved by calling [`-resetTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514782-resettransform).

Comment: Thanks, with resetTransform it is working. The scnactions are not needed anymore, as it already resets the object to the start position. If I use it in the completionHandler of runAction I get a different and stange result. To combine it with scnactions you would maybe need to adapt the transform yourself.